# Graphs with mutiple edges: obtaining neighbours of a vertex and generating random graphs of such nature

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Suppose I have a multigraph $G$, i.e.,

[image]

When I call the function

```
IncidenceList[G,5]
```

I get the result

```
 {5 <-> 1, 5 <-> 4, 5 <-> 4, 5 <-> 4}
```

What command should I use to convert this result to the list that contains neighbours of the vertex 5 with appropriate multiplicity, i.e. I would like to get the list

```
{1,4,4,4}
```

Additionally, is there a way in Mathematica to generate random graphs with multiple edges? This is needed since I am writing a particular function that computes a metric on such type of graph, and hence I would like to be able to test it.

Comment: The [beta version of IGraph/M](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78872/graphs-networks-igraph-m-etc) has a preliminary [function called `IGAdjacencyList`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/McMFo.png).  It does take into account edge multiplicities (unlike `AdjacencyList`).  Feedback is welcome, especially feedback arising from practical needs.

Comment: As for "random graphs with multiple edges", you'd have to give a precise definition of what you want. There are countless possible interpretations of that description.

Comment: For the random graph - anything that, say, emulates the behaviour of RandomGraph[{n,m}] and produces the graph with multiple edges between some of the pairs of the nodes. I am not necessarily looking for any particular degree distribution (although if it would be possible to simulate "small world" type of network with a power law degree distribution, that would be an added bonus).

Comment: `randomGraph[vcount_, ecount_] := 
 Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ 
   Table[RandomSample[Range[vcount], 2], {ecount}]]`

Comment: Thank you - it works perfectly. Could it be possible to update this function so that it would generate mixed graphs (graphs with both directed and undirected edges)?

Comment: Again, you have to define the problem precisely. BTW graphs with both directed and undirected edges are called *mixed* graphs, not multigraphs. Multigraphs are graphs with multiple edges.

Comment: Again, all that would be needed is a graph that emulates the behaviour of RandomGraph[{n,m}] with some of the nodes having multiple edges connecting them, and some of these edges being directed ones and some of these edges being undirected ones. There is no requirement for a specific degree distribution. Ability to generate such graphs randomly is needed in order to check the correctness of the function that computes a particular centrality measure.

Comment: I understand the set you want to sample from, but I do not understand what probabilities you would sample each element with. If uniform, `randomGraph2[vcount_, ecount_] := 
 Graph[RandomChoice[{UndirectedEdge, DirectedEdge}] @@ # & /@ 
   Table[RandomSample[Range[vcount], 2], {ecount}]]`.  Terms like "random" shouldn't be thrown around loosely.  You need to be aware of what distribution you are sampling from. It's an all too common mistake students make, and it *will* introduce biases in your results.

Comment: I understand the need for accuracy when it comes to terminology like "random" in scientific analysis. At the same time, this random graph generation is only needed to test that the centrality measure computing function that I have written gives the same results as does the equivalent function in Mathematica. It would be tiresome to create these test cases by hand - hence the need for "random" graph generation.

Comment: IGraph/M also includes several centrality measures, and you can use it to verify Mathematica's implementations.  I would be very careful with mixed graphs because it is not at all clear what is the "correct" way to calculate various measures for them.  I would definitely not trust Mathematica's choices without verification. In fact, I am not aware of any applications where mixed graphs are truly needed except for certain special graph colouring problems.  For anything else, put reciprocal directed edges where you'd put an undirected edge. Note that IGraph/M does not support mixed graphs.

Comment: If you find concerning differences between Mma, IGraph/M and your implementation, please do let me know in the chatroom I linked to.

Comment: Such graphs may potentially arise in social network analysis - where undirected edge between vertices v1 and v2 represents a relationship like "v1 and v2 are friends" and a directed edge v1 -> v2 represents "v1 sent a message to v2".

Comment: I would say that in that case you have two different and independent kinds of relations, which can be represented with two graphs on the same set of vertices (i.e. a multilayer network). You could also have more than two types of relations.

Comment: I consider the decision to include mixed graphs in Mathematica a very bad one. For every graph measure and every algorithm, it is necessary to come to a decision about how to handle them, and probably implement several special cases. That's on top of the complexity introduced by having to handle all combinations of directed/undirected graphs, loop-free / loopy graphs, multigraphs, weighted/unweighted graphs.  It's a waste of time of the developers, and a recipe for more bugs.

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
other[v1_][UndirectedEdge[v1_, v2_]] := v2
other[v1_][UndirectedEdge[v2_, v1_]] := v2
```

Then,

```
g = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3}]

other[2] /@ IncidenceList[g, 2]
(* {1, 1, 3} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
IncidenceList[##] /. UndirectedEdge[OrderlessPatternSequence[#2, v_]] :> v &[G, 5]
```

> {1, 4, 4, 4}

Also

```
Cases[EdgeList[#] , UndirectedEdge[OrderlessPatternSequence[#2, v_]] :> v] &[G, 5]
```

> {1, 4, 4, 4}

Answer (score 1):

This was easier than I though - the result I was looking for could be obtained with:

```
DeleteCases[Flatten[List @@@ EdgeList[IncidenceList[G, 5]]], 5]
```